# .htaccess not working with files tag

Tags: .htaccess

I have a working wordpress site that already has an .htaccess file with the following content :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But when I try to add the below line it throws a 500 error.

```
<Files *.zip>
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

Can anyone guide me on this ? The server is running on Ubuntu, if that helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did not load `mod_headers`.

If using Debian (or some other Debian derrivative), use `sudo a2enmod headers` to load it. For other systems, read the appropriate documentation.

Anyway, you might want to consider putting those lines an an `<IfModule ...>` statement like the block above:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<Files *.zip>
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
</IfModule>
```